# Verifying a Step in the Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to understand a step of [proof for the open mapping theorem on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)#Proof).

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, $U$ and $V$ be unit balls centered at the origin in each space, respectively. $A$ is a continuous surjective map. The proof then makes the proof progresses to the following statement (right before equation 1):

$V\subseteq \overline{A\left (LU \right )}$ where $L=\frac{2k}{r}$ (some constant for my purpose here)

They claim this implies:
$\forall y \in Y,  \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists x \in X: \qquad \|x\|_X \le L \|y\|_Y \quad \text{and} \quad \|y - Ax\|_Y < \varepsilon. \qquad$

How do I see this? I think they are using continuity for the first inequality, but doesn't the closure of $A(LU)$ affect this conclusion? The second inequality I'm less sure about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since scalar multiplication by $L$ is a homeomorphism, you can rewrite the assumption $V \subset \overline{A(LU)}$ as $\frac{1}{L}V \subset \overline{A(U)}$ (if you want). Now take any nonzero $y \in Y$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Then $\frac{y}{L||y||} \in \frac{1}{L}V$. Hence, for any $\delta > 0$, there is $x' \in U$ such that $||\frac{y}{L||y||}- Ax'|| < \delta$. Set $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{L||y||}$, multiply through by $L||y||$ and set $x := L||y||x'$. Hope this helps.